# My AJAX function works correctly, but sometimes I get a JSON object undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

i am building the next interface:

[image]

as you can see, this interface has two links shown as buttons, one to add products and the other one to rest products.

when i click in the link "addProduct" then it calculates the new total which is shown in the following interface:

[image]

The code involved in this operation, involves 2 files:

JQuery Ajax File:

```
$.ajax({
        async:true,
        type:"POST",
        url: "masProducto.php",
        datatype:"JSON",
        data: {
            tecantidad: tecantidad.val(), 
            valorId:id
        },
        success:function (jsonStr) {
            var cantidad=jsonStr.cantidad;
            var fila=$("#ticket_"+jsonStr.id);
            var tetotal=fila.find(".precioTotal");
            var teprecio=parseFloat(fila.find("input[type=hidden]").val());
            var teCosteTotal=$("#importeTotal");
            teCosteTotal.text(jsonStr.total+"€");
            tetotal.text(teprecio*cantidad+"€");
            var resumenTotal=$("#resumenTicket td:nth-child(3)");
            resumenTotal.text(jsonStr.total+"€");
            var resumenNumProductos=$("#resumenTicket td:nth-child(1)");
                resumenNumProductos.text(jsonStr.numTotalProductos+" Items en la cesta");
        },
        error:function(err){
            alert(err);
        },
        timeout:4000
    });
```

The file masProducto.php where the JSON object is built:

```
<?php 
include 'functions.php';
include('./ShoppingCart.php');
include('./Item.php');
sec_session_start(); //Nuestra manera personalizada segura de iniciar sesión php.

if (!isset($_SESSION['cesta'])){
      header('Location: ./login.php?error=1');
}
else {
    $cesta=new ShoppingCart();
    $cesta=unserialize($_SESSION['cesta']);
}


header('Content-Type: application/json');

$listaItems=$cesta->getItems();
$numEltos=$cesta->count();
$tecantidad=$_POST['tecantidad'];
$id=$_POST['valorId'];

foreach ($listaItems as $celda){
    if($id===$celda['item']->getId()){
        $cesta->updateItem($celda['item'],$tecantidad);
    }
}
    $_SESSION['cesta']=serialize($cesta);


if(isset($id)){
        $data = array(
            "cantidad"   => $tecantidad,
            "id"  => $id,
            "total" => $cesta->calcularTotal(),
            "numTotalProductos" => $numEltos

        );
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

?>
```

I am using PHP OOP, and i use to objects for my shopping basket which are the "Soppingcart" and "Item".

My problem is that this code works right, but when i click fast to the plus (or rest button), it gives me back an undefined object.

I would apreciate if some could help me, because i dont even know how to look for the solution for this problem.

for more details you can enter in this website www.galeonweb.es/Index.php, where if you loggin with "test@example.com" and password "123456" you can see what is my problem better.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I cannot seem to find the "next interface" on your website. Please include steps to reproduce. I would also advice using something like Firebug (on Firefox) to debug AJAX requests & responses if you aren't already it helps tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

First off this line is pretty bad practice

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['cesta'])){
      header('Location: ./login.php?error=1');
}
```

You should rather have something like

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['cesta'])){
      echo json_encode(array(code => 2, message => 'Session invalid'));
}
```

And redirect the user to the login page from jQuery.
You would then need to modify the rest accordingly

```
if(isset($id)){
        $data = array(
            "code" => 0,
            "message" => "Success",
            "data" => array(
                "cantidad"   => $tecantidad,
                "id"  => $id,
                "total" => $cesta->calcularTotal(),
                "numTotalProductos" => $numEltos
             )

        );
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

I would also add the following to that

```
else {

    echo json_encode(array('code' => 1, 'message' => 'Item not found' ));
}
```

Furthermore rather than test if an id is passed at the very end I would do

```
if(isset($id)){
    $found = false;

    foreach ($listaItems as $celda){
        if($id===$celda['item']->getId()){
            $cesta->updateItem($celda['item'],$tecantidad);
            $found = true;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo json_encode(array(code => 1, message => 'Fatal error, id not set'));
}
```

And replace

```
if(isset($id)){
        $data = array(
```

With

```
if($found === true){
        $data = array(
```

You'll of course have to adapt your javascript accordingly to parse the response.
Those changes should give you a better idea of what is going wrong. But, as I said in my comment, using a debug tool like Firebug will also go a long way.

Comment: it seems right your solution, but i still dont know what i should do in case i get the code=2. if i lose my session, how shall i get it back? and why do i lose my session?, thanks in advance

Comment: Well you can loose the session if the user decides to clean out his cookies for example. In the vast majority of cases it won't happen but you still have to check for it just in case. As to what to do if you loose the session it depends on your application. You could also avoid using sessions here by passing the itemlist as an array in your $.ajax function.

Comment: ok, thank you indeed. I think the solution that you propouse is the right one, but i wonder why i keep losing my session when i add products quickly.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried non async?

```
$.ajax({
    async:false,
    type:"POST",
    url: "masProducto.php",
    datatype:"JSON",
...
```

Comment: Eeeck!  `async: false` is never a good idea as it just freezes all interaction in the browser for the duration of the ajax call.

Comment: @jfriend00 you are making the assumption there that all scenarios where xhr is used, is that it is in a multi-threaded (I don't care when I get this response back) environment. For stepped processes where you don't want to do a full page post, `async: false` is what you want. So you can't say it's "never" a good idea on the basis that it "freezes all interaction" as every situation is different

Comment: @danrichardson indeed, there are entirely valid scenarios where you might even _want_ the page frozen. Just as an example, you can have a page that accepts input and then produces some output without reloading or whatever. It could be a button for "Request ticket" which comes back with a ticket (of some form). And since you don't need or even want user interaction in the mean time, you can happily just show a loading animation and have an `async: false` call. Sure, chances are _most_ AJAX calls would be asynchronous (it's in the name) but not certainly not all (that's why the flag is there).

Comment: @danrichardson - I've never ever seen a design where a synchronous ajax call is better than a properly designed async ajax call.  There are many cases where it's easier to code, but not where it's actually a better user experience.  If I find a site using synchronous ajax calls and locking up the browser, I'm ditching that site quickly.  It just doesn't have to be done that way, ever.

Comment: @Vld - you don't need to "freeze the whole browser" in order to keep users from double clicking buttons, etc...   There are better ways to protect the page while waiting for an async ajax call to finish.  Switching to synchronous may be the "cheap" way to code, but it doesn't deliver a better overall user experience.

Comment: Darn.. should have explained myself a bit more and this should have been a comment. I meant to disable async as a debug test to make sure that multiple server requests are to blame. This is ofcourse no definitive solution! Last time I post in a hurry ;-)